# Howcan I get the colormatrix of colorchannelmixer of ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, colormatrix, colormatrixfilter

I want to add some color filter to video, just like image below:
[image]

colorchannelmixer need a 4x4 ColorMatrix, Where can I find this ColorMatrix, or which tool can help me to figure out some ColorMatrix.

(I found a tool called ColorMatrixViewer.exe, but it's a 5x5 ColorMatrix, I just extract a 4x4 maxtrix from it and apply the 4x4 maxtix to colorchannelmixer, theirs result are different)

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Show the command you tried. Unless your image is semi-transparent, alpha is 1 and you can skip that row/column, so just a 3x3 is sufficient. You may be interested in the [`curves`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#curves-1) filter.

Comment: Thank you very much, the **curves** filter is actually what I need. I fond some filter from [android-gpuimage-plus](https://github.com/wysaid/android-gpuimage-plus). There some filter:  1. `@curve R(0, 0)(71, 74)(164, 165)(255, 255) @pixblend screen 0.94118 0.29 0.29 1 20`  2. `@adjust hsv -0.7 0.5 -0.7 -0.7 0 0 @pixblend ol 0.2941 0.5529 0.06665 1 25`  and I have some questions.<br/> 1. I fond [blend](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#blend_002c-tblend) filter, but how to use it with the value of `@pixblend screen`  2. I can not find which filter equals to `@adjust hsv` and `pixblend ol`

Answer (score 0):

I needed to tint a video orange and came up with this:

```
ffmpeg -i <inputfile> -vf colorchannelmixer=1:0:0:0:0:.5:0:0:0:0:0 -acodec copy -pix_fmt yuv420p <outputfile>
```

Alternately, I've also used a 2 step process to convert the video to black & white, then to orange:

```
ffmpeg -i <inputfile> -vf hue=s=0 -acodec copy <outputfile>
ffmpeg -i <outputfile> -vf colorchannelmixer=1:0:0:0:0:.5:0:0:0:0:0 -acodec copy -pix_fmt yuv420p <outputfile2>
```